# Using multiple files in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im starting a new iPhone app, and Im sick of doing them the 'lazy way'; i.e. all of the code in one view controller. I want to control the levels form a different .m (or with XML). How do I, say, have a CGPoint declared in Level.h, controlled in Level.m, and accessed in Game.m?

Thanks,
Conor

Comment: Check this out. It's not specific to Objective-C, but will guide you none the less. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84ydca5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: import the classes and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

in Levels.h:

```
@interface Levels : NSObject {

}

+(CGPoint)levelController;
```

in Levels.m:

```
+(CGPoint)levelController {
    CGPoint wall_01;
    wall_01 = CGPointMake(300, 100);
    return wall_01;
}
```

in Game.m:

```
test = [Levels levelController];//in any method you want, just import "Levels.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassA.h

@interface ClassA : BaseClass
{

    CGPoint point;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) CGPoint point;
@end

ClassB.h

#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassB : BaseClass
{

    ClassA classa;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) ClassA classa;
@end

ClassB.m

CGPoint localPoint = classa.point
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to think in terms of code in file A talking to code in file B. This is *object* oriented programming, so think in terms of objects talking to each other. Any object can talk to any other object to which it has a reference (pointer). Organizing your program so that the objects that need to talk to each other can do so is one of the most important tasks that you do as a software developer.

Comment: Do what? Organize your program? That depends on your program. It's part of creating your program. There are a number of common patterns for how objects communicate with each other, the most important of which in iOS is MVC. Delegation is another. Listener is another. Read *Cocoa Fundamentals Guide* to learn how to use these patterns to put together an iOS app.